# Having trouble with my code working for IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseover

This code works inside my coffee cup test browser but when I test in other browsers it doesn't work at all. None of the features work, drag and drop, highlight text on focus, and cursor change on mouse over.

Here's some code I put together:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
            function handleMouseMove(oEvent) {
                if (oEvent.button == 1) {
                    oEvent.srcElement.dragDrop();
                }
            }
            
            function handleDragDropEvent(oEvent,nm) {
                oEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text",""+nm+"");
            }
            
            function SelectAll(id) {
                document.getElementById(id).focus();
                document.getElementById(id).select();
            }
            
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <table border="0"  width="25%">
            <td align="left"><div style="background-color: transparent"       onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onmousemove="handleMouseMove(event)" ondragstart="handleDragDropEvent(event,['S.D.'])"><b><font color="#0080FF">S.D.</font></b></div></td><!-- Col 1 -->
            <td align="center"><font size="1">5.2</font></td><!-- Col 2 -->
            <td align="right"><div style="background-color: transparent" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onmousemove="handleMouseMove(event)" ondragstart="handleDragDropEvent(event,['G.B.'])">G.B.</div></td><!-- Col 3 -->
        </table>
        <br /><br />

     <b>16: </b><input type="text" id="16" onClick="SelectAll('16');" name="16" size="12" tabindex=3 value="" />
    </body> 
</html>
```

I would also like to remove text on drop, so if the textbox has text in it, what drops in will replace and not add to it. Please help.

Comment: first thing you should know is you are working with javascript, not java

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

1. The "hand"-cursor isn't called "hand", but "pointer"
2. The ondragstart event isn't supported by every browser, as it is HTML5
3. and an id/name must beginn with a letter

It would be better to use something like jQuery (+ plug-ins) for all of these events.